# Azure devops pipeline improperly formed cron syntax

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, cron-task

Trying to set up a cron on azure devops pipeline but I am getting this error message. I looked at the documentation but not sure what is not in line with the doc. Could someone let me know what is wrong with the my cron syntax? Thank you.

```
Error while validating cron input. Improperly formed cron syntax: '0 21 * * 1-7'.
```

Here is the entire yml file.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
  - master

schedules:
  - cron: "0 21 * * 1-7"
    displayName: "pipeline cron test"
    branches:
      include: 
      - master
    always: true



pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - script: echo Hello, world!
    displayName: Run a one-line script, changed

  - script: |
      echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
      echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
      echo more info
    displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

Here's the relevant part of the doc.

```
Building Cron Syntax
Each cron syntax consists of 5 values separated by Space character:

1
2
3
4
5
6
mm HH DD MM DW
 \  \  \  \  \__ Days of week
  \  \  \  \____ Months
   \  \  \______ Days
    \  \________ Hours
     \__________ Minutes
We can use following table to create understand syntax:

Syntax  Meaning Accepted Values
mm  Minutes 0 to 59
DD  Hours   0 to 23
MM  Months  1 through 12, full English names, first three letters of English names
DW  Days of the Week    0 through 6 (starting with Sunday), full English names, first three letters of English names
Values can be provided in following formats:
 

Format  Example Description
Wildcard    *   Matches all values for this field
Single value    5   Specifies a single value for this field
Comma delimited 3,5,6   Specifies multiple values for this field. Multiple formats can be combined, like 1,3-6
Ranges  1-3 The inclusive range of values for this field
Intervals   */4 or 1-5/2    Intervals to match for this field, such as every 4th value or the range 1-5 with a step interval of 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your CRON syntax like the following:  "0 21 * * *" or "0 21 * * 0-6", if you want to trigger it for all days of the week.

> Days of week: 0 through 6 (starting with Sunday), full English names,
> first three letters of English names